# Combine 2 Vectors

Tags: r, vector, intervals

I am quite a beginner in R and I try to simplify my current code.

So I want to define intervals between 1 and 'nb' by 'step' increment

Let's say that nb = 3200 and step = 1000

The result should be

```
[[1]]
[1]    1 1001

[[2]]
[1] 1001 2001

[[3]]
[1] 2001 3001

[[4]]
[1] 3001 3200
```

I have those two vectors

```
X: [1]     1 1001 2001 3001
M: [1]  1000 2000 3000 3200
```

Edit: 
I finaly found a way to do that

```
X <- seq(1, nb, step)
M <- pmin(X + step - 1, nb)
tmp <- cbind(X, M)
intervals <- split(tmp, row(tmp))
```

Maybe someone could have a faster solution ?

Comment: What are you planning to do with `[ [1, 1000], [1001, 2000], [2001, 3000], [3001, 3200] ]`? If you just want to break a vector into chunks, check out `?cut`

Comment: I want to parallelize stuff over data.table
I build subset of my data.table according to the intervals

Comment: Hm, I'm not a `data.table` expert but does `data.table` include parallelization functions? I thought this would need other packages.. (Correct me if I'm wrong). Maybe it'd be better if you ask a question with a minimal example of what you're trying to parallelize in data.table..

Comment: I allready have the parallelization part
I also have a way to build intervals
I just want to make my code easier to read

Comment: Do you actually want/need to have all those `[` and `]` in the output or is this just for demonstration purposes? You say you already got this result by using `lapply` - which returns a list and not what you indicate in your question. If `lapply` already does what you want, is there a reason why you're looking for a different approach? The desired result with all the  `[` inside looks rather unusual for R code - at least for me.

Comment: I edit my question with true print of R

Comment: Is there a question here? It seems like you figured all out

Comment: Are you looking for `rbind(X, M)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
X <- seq(1, nb, step)
M <- pmin(X + step - 1, nb)
tmp <- cbind(X, M)
intervals <- split(tmp, row(tmp))
```